# Typescript typed array not displaying data

Tags: angular, typescript, typed-arrays

I am using Angular 7 and Typescript 3 to create a pre-populate array of ingredients in a service that will be used in a component but when I print the array out to the console, I am getting an array of empty  objects.

If I create the typed array using object literals it will work, but if I create the array using the new operator, the array, will not contain any data.

EDITED: Added snippet of ingredient class

```
export class Ingredient {
    constructor(name?: string, amount?: number, measurement?: string) {}
}
```

This contains data:

```
export class ShoppingListService {
  private ingredients: Ingredient[] = [{
    name: 'shrimp',
    amount: 1,
    measurement: 'cup'
  },
  {
    name: 'bib lettuce',
    amount: 1,
    measurement: 'bunch'
  }];
  constructor() { 
   console.log('ingredients', this.ingredients);
   }
```

console output:

```
ingredients [{name: "shrimp", amount: 1, measurement: "cup"},
             {name: "bib lettuce", amount: 1, measurement: "bunch"}
            ]
```

This this doesn't contain data

```
export class ShoppingListService {
  private ingredients = [
    new Ingredient('shrimp', 1, 'cup'),
    new Ingredient('bib lettuce', 1, 'bunch')
  ];

  constructor() {
    console.log('ingredients', this.ingredients);
   }
}
```

console output:

```
ingredients [Ingredient{}, Ingredient{}]
```

I have also tried using the following syntax, but I get the same output as the example above:

```
private ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
    new Ingredient('shrimp', 1, 'cup'),
    new Ingredient('bib lettuce', 1, 'bunch')
  ];
```

is there some typescript or angular logic that I am missing here? The example above is used in the Angular docs here:
[Angular: Using the Hero class](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#using-the-hero-class)

Comment: You must have forgotten to set the constructor for Ingredient class properly. That's the issue i can assume. By the way what's the problem with first logic? Can't you follow that?

Comment: What's the `Ingredient` class look like?

Comment: I think there are some issue with Ingredient class it would be great if you write your Ingredient class so we can identify what want wrong

Comment: @Yash Rami here is my Ingredient class. I decided to use Typescript parameter properties. Should I just have used the Automatic Constructor instead? the reason I didn't was because I didn't think it gave me getters and setters with it as well.

Comment: @Arcteezy there is no problem with doing it the first way except I am seeing tutorials from the Angular Doc and from watch other people's tutorials that are doing that way and it seems like it should work, but it isn't. So I was trying to figure out what I am doing wrong or missing.

Comment: @androgirl you need to use constructor to assign a value to member variable so we get the value and assign that value to respective variable.

Comment: If you want the constructor parameters to become properties, you need to give them a visibility, otherwise they are simple parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**Working code for both scenario** 


//ingredient.ts

export class Ingredient{
  constructor(public  name: string, public id: number, public measurment: string){
  }  
}

//ingredient.component.ts

    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import { Ingredient } from './ingredient ';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-ingredient',
      template: 'Ingredient'
    })
    export class IngredientComponent{
        private ingredients: Ingredient[] = [{
        name: 'shrimp',
        id: 1,
        measurment: 'cup'
      },
      {
        name: 'bib lettuce',
        id: 1,
        measurment: 'bunch'
      }];
    /*
      ingredients = [
        new Ingredient('shrimp', 1, 'cup'),
        new Ingredient('bib lettuce', 1, 'bunch')
      ];
    */

      constructor(){
    console.log(this.ingredients);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Esakki, your answer was the closest to what the actual solution was. but since I was trying to get the answer to why `[ new Ingredient(....), new Ingredient(...)]` wasn't working, if you modify your answer by uncommenting out the second set of code and remove the object literals, i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So i think you need to these changes in your Ingredient class

```
export class Ingredient {
   constructor(data?: any) {
     this.name = data.name;
     this.amount = data.amount;
     this.measurement = data.measurement;
   }
   public name: string = null;
   public amount: number = null;
   public measurement: string = null;
}
```

And inside your component for setting a data

```
 private ingredients = [
    new Ingredient({
     name: 'bib lettuce',
     amount: 1, 
     measurement: 'bunch'
    })
  ];
```

```
console.log(ingredients);
```

I hope it helps you out

Comment: shouldn't I be able to use parameter properties to do this? [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#8.3.1)